# Remover locais e pontos/paradas de ônibus do Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Tenho este seguinte código:

```
<script>
  function init() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.04, -118.24);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
```

No qual gera esse este mapa abaixo em uma `div` qualquer. Eu circulei de vermelho alguns locais no qual não quero que apareça no mapa. Aliás, não gostaria que não mostrasse nenhum local no mapa, apenas o papa com ruas e rodovias:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível remover todos os locais e  pontos/paradas de ônibus do Google Maps? Se sim, qual seria a maneira mais viável de fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ocultar os pontos de interesse (**POI's**) do teu mapa, basta adicionar o seguinte estilo nas opções do mapa:

```
styles:[{
      "featureType": "poi",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
}]
```

Para ocultar as paradas de ônibus:

```
styles:[{
      "featureType": "transit.station.bus",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
}]
```

Acho interessante compartilhar também, um site que auxilia na customização do mapa: [Mapstyle](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

Segue um JsFiddle com um exemplo utilizando o código apresentado na pergunta: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/a9akruf3/2/)

Comment: Não removeram os pontos/paradas de ônibus =/

Comment: @acklay atualizei o fiddle na resposta, agora oculta paradas de ônibus também, nota que estações de metrô continuam visíveis.

Comment: @acklay eu realmente não sei se é uma "boa" maneira, mas aqui nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406636/how-to-remove-all-from-google-map), tudo é ocultado, posteriormente somente as rodovias são exibidas.

Comment: Coloque o que está no JsFiddle na sua resposta.